# How to let pytest know that a new test begins

Tags: pytest

In a Python project, we have a function test that specifies test input and expected results in a set of yaml files in a directory. We have code that loops over the yaml files in the directory, and loops over the test cases in each yaml file, and then executes the test case.

We currently run the whole script that drives these loops as a single test case under pytest. That clutters up the display, because we print info which testcase is currently executing, and has some other disadvantages.

We would like to change this so that each test case in each yaml file becomes known to pytest as a separate test case.

How can this be achieved?

Basically, I am hoping that the loops in our test case driver script can remain there and in the inner loop, we can simply let pytest know that a new test case begins. But of course, I'm open to other solutions as well.

Comment: Wouldn't [the example in `pytest` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/nonpython.html) of test lookup in yaml files be a much better solution than a custom collector? If not, then providing an example of yaml result pairs would be helpful. I guess there are other ways, like test parametrizing via `metafunc` in `pytest_generate_tests` hook or implementing custom `pytest_pycollect_makeitem` hook like `mypy` does it, for example.

Comment: @hoefling I finally resumed this work, and tried to use the approach you referenced. It worked great! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!